# changing the plot graph in my matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, graphics, plot

my aim is, after having a graph plotted in my gui, and all the peaks have a X plotted on them using some 'peak find' function, to be able to correct manually the location of the Xes, by moving them or erasing the wrong ones..

I am not sure how can I access the graph after it is plotted to change the location of some Xes or to erase other ones.

Comment: Why must you move your markers instead of only plotting the ones you want in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: misread Xes for axis

You should just change the variable that is the output of your peak find function and contains the location of the Xes and plot the picture again.